# a11y issues on WordPress - google lighthouse can't detect <label></label> on the form on the hero section

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have an issue with my client's WordPress site where I can't fix and find where I should add the `<label></label>` on the form which is triggering the a11y on Google Lighthouse
[image]

I'm quite new to tinkering with php and wordpress and I can only understand a little php so please bear with me. This is what's on the hero.php

```
        <div class="hero-optin">
        <?php if ( ! empty( $hero['title'] ) || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
            <h1 class="hero-title mb-small caps"><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $hero['title'] ); ?></h1>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( ! empty( $hero['description'] ) || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
            <div class="hero-text mb-single">
                <?php echo wpautop( $hero['description'] ); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php md_email_form( array(
            'email_title' => false,
            'email_desc' => false,
            'email_input' => array( 'name' => true ),
            'email_submit_text' => ! empty( $hero['email_submit'] ) ? esc_html( $hero['email_submit'] ) : __( 'Join Now!', 'mb' ),
            'email_form_footer' => ! empty( $hero['email_footer'] ) ? esc_html( $hero['email_footer'] ) : ''
        ) ); ?>
        </div>
```

How and where would I add the `<label></label>` to fix this issue?

Anyone know this?

Comment: Find the `md_email_form()` function, that's what builds your form. You'll find your labels and the fields in there.

Comment: @cabrerahector I'd find this on the functions.php file or where?

Comment: I'd look inside the functions.php file first, yes, since that's not a core WP function. If it's not there then it may be coming from a plugin.

Comment: Would you have an idea about the name of the plugin? It looks like it's not one of these https://highcenburgtech.files.wordpress.com/2020/01/screen-shot-2020-01-09-at-9.06.32-am.png

Comment: No idea, sorry. Try using a code editor (eg. Visual Studio Code) to search for the function. You may need to download your theme folder and your entire plugins folder to do the search (assuming you don't have a local copy of the site on your computer.)